# Unsure about how to actually get my project up and running on Heroku Web

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to set up a NodeJS-MongoDB MQTT subscriber that receives the payload and pushes it into the MongoDB database.

However, when I try to run `heroku open` , I get this error.

[image: Error from trying to run]

Furthermore, on the web link, I receive an 'Application error'.

This is what my `Procfile` looks like:

```
web: node app.js $PORT
```

Furthermore, as requested, my app.js code is as shown:

```
 var axios = require('axios');
 var mqtt = require('mqtt');
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 /*
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var dbName = "MPProject";
var port = "27017";
var host = "localhost";
*/
var connectionString = [CENSORED FOR STACK OVERFLOW];
mongoose.connect(connectionString);

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error('Database connection error:', error);
});

mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Database connected');
});

var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://test.mosquitto.org")

// var a = getNumOfDocs("IoTGreenhouseData",host,port,dbName,function (err,count){
//     if (err){
//         return console.log(err.message);
//     }
//     console.log('number of documents',count);
// })

var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes();


function insertData(message,datetime){
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "collection": "IoTGreenhouseData",
        "database": "MPProject",
        "dataSource": "Cluster0",
        "document": {
            "text":message.toString(),
            "time":datetime
        }
    });
    return data;
}

/*
var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-rrokr/endpoint/data/beta/action/insertOne`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers': '*',
        'api-key': [CENSORED FOR STACK OVERFLOW]
    },
    data : insertData()
};
*/
client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected')
    client.subscribe(["mp/ph"], () => {
    console.log(`Subscribe to topic 'mp/ph'`)
    })
})

client.on('message',function(topic,payload){
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes();
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-rrokr/endpoint/data/beta/action/insertOne`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers': '*',
            'api-key': 'xmNZ31KLLr2nd1rOsFcSBKohUOWZNPxXlnrDdVQlc2Fu0ugm308OBDv7c5SgRGIh'
        },
        data : insertData(payload,datetime)
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

[Error logs 2]
[image]

```
2022-07-23T01:20:37.932429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-23T01:20:38.030691+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-23T01:24:37.086275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=iotseedgermination.herokuapp.com request_id=b5b846cd-9497-4337-9bc5-e69ba5c123ef fwd="[REMOVED FOR STACK OVERFLOW]" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-23T01:24:37.388143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=iotseedgermination.herokuapp.com request_id=6239812a-7594-4f70-86b6-b1fc46d1c13c fwd="[REMOVED FOR STACK OVERFLOW]" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

```
worker: node app.js
```

Could it perhaps be the actual code isn't highlighted in my Procfile?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Your `Procfile` definitely shouldn't include Python code (and why are you including Python code if your app is builtin JavaScript in the first place?). Remove lines 2 and 3, then please [edit] your `app.js` into your question as a code block (not an image).

Comment: @Chris         As you requested, I've made the suggestions. Hopefully, this will help you get a better idea of my issue. Thank you.

Comment: None of that code appears to listen for HTTP requests. Is it supposed to, or does it just use that MQTT connection?

Comment: @Chris         It's supposed to just use the MQTT connection.

Answer (score 0):

Since your application doesn't listen for HTTP requests it should not be declared as a `web` process. Instead, declare it as a `worker`:

```
worker: node app.js
```

Note that the port is irrelevant now. Only `web` processes need to be aware of the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: I've tried that, however it still seems to be giving errors. Edited original post for details [Error logs 2]